# Why Am I Not Able to Access state Through a Link Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've tried making tons of small changes to this code snippet (extra curly braces, changing ':' to '=' in the Link component code, and still location.state is null is on the ReportEdit component I'm trying to pass state to. Is this not something that is possible in React Router Dom 6.2.1?

Here's the code

Component drawing the link

```
<Link 
  to={`/report/${report.id}/edit`}
  state={{hi: "hi"}}>
 <Button>
    Edit
 </Button>
</Link>
```

Linked component I want to pass state to

```
import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Link, useParams, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios';

const ReportEdit = props => {

  const [report, setReport] = useState([]);
  const [ rep_type, setRepType ] = useState(report.rep_type);
  const [ rep_count, setRepCount ] = useState(report.rep_count);

  let params = useParams()
  const location = useLocation()

  console.log(location.state) // <--- always 'null'

  const id = params.id

  //async function handleSubmit() {
    //let data = await axios.put(`http://localhost:3001/reports/${id}`)
   // if (data) {
     // console.log(data.data.report)
    //}
  //}

  return (
    <div>
      <Form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)}>
        <Form.Group className="mb-1" controlId="rep_type">
          <Form.Control 
            type="text" 
            placeholder={props.rep_type}
            name="rep_type"
            value={rep_type}
            onChange={e => setRepType(e.target.value)} 
          />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group className="mb-1" controlId="rep_count">
          <Form.Control 
            type="number" 
            placeholder={props.rep_count} 
            name="rep_count"
            value={rep_count} 
            onChange={e => setRepCount(e.target.value)} 
          />
        </Form.Group>
      <Button variant="primary" type="submit">Submit</Button>
    </Form>
  </div>
  )
}

export default ReportEdit;
```

Comment: Assuming `ReportEdit` is rendered by the route you are linking to I don't think I see any overt issues here. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Are you *sure* you are using `react-router-dom` v6? From your project directory please run `npm list react-router react-router-dom` and report back the installed version.

Comment: @DrewReese - output: react-router-dom@6.2.1  - react-router@6.2.1. Working on the sandbox now. Thanks

Comment: @DrewReese well, it's working in the sandbox lol. Trying to figure out what's different :shrug:

Comment: @DrewReese https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-stitch-brm2k?file=/src/App.js:432-442

Comment: @DrewReese, I figured it out - I had to use the link navigation to pass state. I was just refreshing the page in development...lol...I love coding

Comment: Cool, glad you got it sorted out. Voting to close as unreproducible. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference to the official [react-router-dom document](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object#Link-to-object), you can pass params through object, for example:

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `/report/${report.id}/edit`,
    state: { id: report.id }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: You linked the v5 docs, OP says they are using v6. in RRDv6 route state is a top-level prop, not a property on the `to` prop object. This answer is incorrect and isn't very helpful.

Comment: In the [v6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#link) docs,  type `To` is `Partial<Location> | string;`. [`Location`](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#location) interface contains the `state`.

Comment: @JosephD. this is what I'm currently trying to do without success.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I was only refreshing the target page in development, and I needed to actually be using the link to pass props via state. fml.